# Upload file from form to s3 bucket using php

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm building a website that allows users to upload a file, which I then want to push to an s3 bucket.

Currently, the script takes the file from a **specific** path on my computer and then uploads it to s3

**Question**
How do I take the file from the **users' computer** and then upload it to s3?

Here is how my php file uploads the file from the form to a specific folder on my computer:

```php
 $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;

          #file destination
          $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;

          #function to change file location
          move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
          header("Location: index.php?uploadsuccess");
```

Here is how my second php file finds the file on my computer and uploads to s3:

```php
$bucketname = 'we-sign-files';
$file_path = '/Users/ddripz/Desktop/wesign/uploads/5f31fc30410c17.68431957.jpg';
$key = basename($file_path);
```

Again these codes snippets take the file from the HTML form and uploads it to a file on my local system; and then s3 accesses the file from the local system and uploads it to the bucket.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! I do not understand what is your intention. Your PHP scripts work on your server, and the file that is uploaded from the users's computer to your server then gets uploaded to the s3. So that is what you want, don't you? Where is the problem? Normally, you cannot upload from web browser form to another page/server than to the one that is shown in the browser. But it's possible I just do not understand what you are aiming at.

Comment: Hi @Palo! Thank you for your kind message! My goal is to take a document that one can upload from my webpage and then store it in s3 so that it can be retrieved later. Are you recommending that this be done a different way?

Comment: I am still confused. Why cannot you just join the two scripts you shown? Is your question about how to join them? (did you try? what problems have you encountered?) or you want to do it in another way?